# From Python function to Django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to get my head around Django and understand how I can show results of Python functions in Django's templates. As a simple example, let's say I have a model with a list of questions and I want to use a function to return the number of questions and for this result to be shown in a template. How can I do it?

I tried to do it below but it doesn't work!

Thanks in advance

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_app import models
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django_app.models import Question



class TestListView(ListView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'test_details'

    def Test(self):
        return Question.objects.count()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django_app import views
from django_app.views import TestListView


app_name = 'django_app'


urlpatterns = [
    path('',TestListView.as_view(), name='Test'),
]
```

**question_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for item in test_details %}

    {{Test}}

    {{item.question_text}}

    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) method of your view to add extra variable into your context

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['Test'] = Question.objects.count()
    return context
```

You can also get the count of the questions without having to alter the context. You can get it from the queryset

```
{{ test_details.count }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why can't we just use {{ Test }}? Is there a general way to write a Python function in views and call it in templates?

Comment: The view is added to the context as "view" so you could call the function as `{{ view.Test }}`

Comment: This site is extremely useful for seeing what is available in the generic views http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_context_data